# How do I prevent MVC unobtrusive validation for required field from also activating email validation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have an ASP.NET MVC login form, that uses client-side unobtrusive validation.

My login model has a UserName with a `[Required]` attribute.
Most of the usernames entered will be email-addresses, so on touch-devices, I'd like to show a nice email-friendly keyboard. So I set `type="email"`on the `<input>`, like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { type = "email" })
```

Now, I don't want to have the email-address validated (since non-email usernames are valid), but somehow, since I have a `[Required]` attribute, the default jquery.validate email validation kicks in as well, giving me a ´Please enter a valid email address´ error.

Is there any way to prevent this, while keeping the required-field validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple:

```
$('#loginform').data("validator").settings.rules["UserName"].email = false;
```

An input field is validated using multiple rule sets (from jquery.validate.js):

```
    var data = $.validator.normalizeRules(
    $.extend(
        {},
        $.validator.metadataRules(element),
        $.validator.classRules(element),
        $.validator.attributeRules(element),
        $.validator.staticRules(element)
    ), element);
```

The `attributeRules` are what cause the email validation to be activated, but since `staticRules` take precendce, the email-validation is de-activated with our assignment above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dum suggestion but how about removing the [Required] attribute and handling it in the controller on post action?  :)

Comment: While that would work, I still prefer to solve it client-side. And as it turned out, the solution was quite simple.

Comment: Hehe, yup.  I might actually borrow that one from you  ;)